# open specific Activity from command line

Tags: android, shell, android-intent, android-manifest, explicit-intent

I'm trying to start a specific Activity from command line.
I'm building the app for Android O (api 26), and i try to explicitly start that activity to simulate a deeplink

the activity manifest

```
<activity
        android:name=".activities.ChatActivity"
        android:label="@string/chat_action_bar_title"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

my package is: package="com.my.app"

and i m useing this command:

```
adb shell am start  -n com.my.app.activities/.ChatActivity
```

and i m getting this error:

```
    Starting: Intent { cmp=com.my.app.activities/.ChatActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.my.app.activities/com.my.app.activities.ChatActivity} does not exist.
```

I tried to add

```
 -a android.intent.action.VIEW
```

and

```
-c android.intent.category.DEFAULT
```

but i cant start that activity,

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So after hours of seeking the unknown i have found the solution.
In my app i m using some BuildVariants to differentiate working phases.

so instead of using the command

```
adb shell am start  -n com.my.app.activities/.ChatActivity
```

I should of used

```
adb shell am start -n com.my.app.MY_BUILD_VARIANT/com.my.app.activities.ChatActivity
```

thanks for the helpers

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the sub package and the launcher intent. Change it to

```
adb shell start -n com.my.app/.activities.ChatActivity
```

Comment: but it is not a launcher activity

Comment: Starting: Intent { cmp=com.my.app/.activities.ChatActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.my.app/com.my.app.activities.ChatActivity} does not exist.

Comment: @soosita Did you install the app on the phone?

Comment: @Murat K. yes i did, both emulator and a real device, they are not connected simultaneously of course.

Comment: @Murat K.Package Changes:
  Sequence number=34
  User 0:
    seq=31, package=com.google.android.gms
    seq=33, package=com.my.app.staging


Dexopt state:
  Unable to find package: com.my.app


Compiler stats:
  Unable to find package: com.my.app

Comment: @ pskink those lines are for Compiler and Dexopt state, what doest it mean?

Comment: @ pskink now my app is running and this is the same dumpsys

Comment: @pskink `Processes: 258 total, 2 running, 256 sleeping, 2090 threads 
2017/12/14 14:55:53`